# What exactly mean ":" when using git show?

Tags: git

To see a file a commit of a file I'm doing `git show filename`
To see not just the changes I'm doing: `git show :filename`

What is it mean the `:`?

Can I use `:`  in other command in git? What is will do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [git-show man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show), this is documented in [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html).

> `<rev>:<path>, e.g. HEAD:README, :README, master:./README`
>
> A suffix : followed by a path names the blob or tree at the given path in the
>   tree-ish object named by the part before the colon.  :path (with an empty part
>   before the colon) is a special case of the syntax described next: content
>   recorded in the index at the given path. A path starting with ./ or ../ is
>   relative to the current working directory. The given path will be converted to
>   be relative to the working tree's root directory. This is most useful to
>   address a blob or tree from a commit or tree that has the same tree structure
>   as the working tree.

That's pretty unclear. It's a way to disambiguate between asking to be shown a revision and asking to be shown a file.

`revision:filename` will show you the filename at a particular revision.

`:filename` without the revision will show you the file as it appears in the staging area (aka "the index").

This will work on commands which can take both a revision or a file path. `git-show` is the only one I can think of.

Comment: `git rev-parse` can take a revision or path, e.g., `git rev-parse branch`, `git rev-parse branch:`, `git rev-parse branch:path`, `git rev-parse :path`, and so on.  `git cat-file -p` and `git cat-file -t` can therefore also do this.  (There might be a few more but none come to mind off-hand.)

Answer (score 2):

In this context, the `:` means to show the full contents of a file at a particular commit, and the the staging area is implied when no other commit hash is specified.

For example, if you had a another hash `fafefefa1313`, you could do the following to show what the file looked like at that commit.

```
git show fafefefa1313:filename
```

Comment: It's not HEAD which is implied, but the staging area.  If `filename` is modified and added, `git show :filename` will show the modified version.